# Extend an Event into Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, debugging, events

I need to extend an event created into a JS file of a Wordpress Plugin.

For example:

> s.on("ready", function (t) {  .... }

How can I do this without modify the plugin (beacause the plugin can be updated and I will lose all the modification)?

I tried nothing because I don't know how to do

Comment: Have you tried adding your own event listener on a separate file / script? Eg. `s.on('ready', your_callback_here);'. Unless by "extend" what you really mean to say is "override"?

Comment: This really needs more details / clarity. With "normal" JS event handing, you would not be able to remove an added listener, if you don't have the reference to the exact function instance that was added, available. This appears to be jQuery syntax though - so you _could_ theoretically remove _all_ handlers that have been added for this event, using `.off()`. But that is probably likely to remove other, essential functionality as well then (not sure what `s` is there, but if that is document, then likely other plugins will have added their own event handlers for this as well.)

Comment: Thanks for help! The event listener i write into my question is the event listener of the plugin, and is inside some other code into the JS file of the plugin. From the console I cannot access the s variable, it's not defined. Yes I want to override it (not extend sorry)

Comment: If the plugin doesn't provide a way to override this event listener then: a) you reach out to the developer, explain your use case and hope they add a way to override their event listener; b) you dequeue their script completely and replace it with one of your own; or c) you fork the plugin and customize it to your needs (but then you'll need to back-port future updates into your version).